# Show that $v(a)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_i+1)$ if $a=\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{\alpha_i}$ and $v(a)$ is the number of positive divisors of $a$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Consider the function $v:\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}\to\mathbb{N},a\mapsto v(a)$, where $v(a)$ is the number of positive divisor of $a$. Show that if $a=\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{\alpha_i}$, where each $p_i$ is a prime number and each $\alpha_i$ is a positive integer, then $v(a) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_i+1)$.

First I defined a set $D(a):=\{b:b\in\mathbb{Z}\land b|a\}$ and wrote $v(a)$ as $v(a) = |\{|b|:b\in D(a)\}|$. Then I wrote $$ D\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{\alpha_i}\right) = \{p_i^{m}:m\in\mathbb{Z}\cap[0,\alpha_i]\land i\in\mathbb{Z}\cap[1,n]\} \quad.$$ But I don't know where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: what are the looks of a positive divisor of $a$ if you write it as a product of primes? Compare this with the look of $a$ itself also written as a product of primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example illustrates the ideas:

Take $a=2^3 \times 3^4 \times 5^7$, then the divisors of $a$ are of the form
$$d=2^p \times 3^q \times 5^r,$$
where $p=0, 1,2, 3, q=0,1,2,3, 4 $ and $r=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7.$

Since there are $(3+1)$ choices for $p$, $(4+1)$ choices for $q$ and $(7+1)$ choices for $r$, there are $(3+1) \times (4+1) \times(7+1) $ different possible values of $d$